# Get all Facebook feeds from my wall and using POST method using FBConnect

Tags: android, fbconnect, feed

I'm trying to implement Facebook features in android Application.
I'm using FBConnect.jar
i have two questions

1. I can post something to wall using following code

   ```
       String response = mFacebook.request("me");
       Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
       parameters.putString("message", msg);
       parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
       response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "GET");
   ```

   Here i have used GET method. Is it possible to use POST method if so what is the syntax
2. Then if i want to get news feeds of my account i use following code

   ```
           JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me/feed"));
           JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
           for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               if(json_data.has("message") && (json_data.has("name"))){
                   String name = json_data.getString("name");
                   String message=json_data.getString("message");
                   Log.i("GET ACTIVITY",String.format("Name is %s and Message is %", name,message));
               }
           }
   ```

Here i can get feeds that are posted by me in my account. But if i want all Facebook feeds that are in my wall (Friends and me). pls give me some sample code too.

Thanks,
Shanmugam.

Answer (score 0):

Try me/home instead of me/feed