# android- get facebook news feed into a string

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried my best to find out a simple way to get the recent news feed of the logged in Facebook user in my android application. It was simple to get the recent Tweet with the Screen name for Twitter. Is there something similar to that. I'm using the standard Facebook sdk that i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

Also is it possible to view the News Feed of the users who have added my mobile application in facebook website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291127/get-all-facebook-feeds-from-my-wall-and-using-post-method-using-fbconnect) helped me , but for some reason , i can't get what others have written to the wall of the current user . only those that the current user has created are included .

if you find out how to overcome this , please let me know.

there are some posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230731/read-wall-of-a-facebook-page-by-using-the-graph-api-possible)) on this forum that say that i need to provide the page id 
 , but i don't understand where do i get such a thing .

Comment: yes , i have recently found that FQL can retrieve things that Graph-API can't . i don't understand why it's like that . can you please post a small sample of what you did ?